# mysql sometimes slow when join with large table

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have this large `User` table with 1 million plus rows. The strange thing is it queries normally for most of the users data, but always take up to 30 seconds for when query for some Users data. It doesn't happen randomly, but always on the particular User(s).

The query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM visit V
INNER JOIN group G ON G.id = V.group_id
INNER JOIN user U ON U.id = V.user_id AND U.group_id = V.parent_group_id
WHERE V.id = xxx AND V.group_id = xxx
```

But if I remove the `JOIN` with the table user, the query is normal again.

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

*(The query is minified, the actual query is very long and also need to be kept confidential)*

Comment: What indexes do you have on the user table?

Comment: I have index for U.id and U.group_id as Primary key, I also index each of them separately, U.id, and U.group_id

Comment: Tuning a query can be difficult and it's hard to give specific advice without more information. One place to start is using `EXPLAIN` to better understand how indexes are currently being used.

Comment: Are v.user_id and v.parent_group_id indexed?

Comment: @flip yes they are indexed properly

Comment: I would definitely post an `EXPLAIN` as mentioned above. Without more information it's really difficult to give advice outside of indices (which it sounds like you're on top of already).

Comment: Also, if you test with the exact query you posted (rather than a 'minified' version), does the problem happen?

Comment: Which do you have on V:  `INDEX(user_id, parent_group_id)`?  Or `INDEX(parent_group_id, user_id)`.  Please provide the `PRIMARY KEY` for each table.

Comment: Does `*` include any `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns?

Comment: Are the tables InnoDB?

Comment: It would be useful to see the actual query

Comment: Although it's not going to be directly related to your problem, it's a bit weird to put a separate index on a column that is already the first column of a multi-column index. (Again, not saying this is related to your performance, but it's generally not a good use of space).

Answer (score 2):

## Joining large datasets requires indices on the JOIN and the WHERE clauses.

```
SELECT * FROM visit V
INNER JOIN group G ON G.id = V.group_id
INNER JOIN user U ON U.id = V.user_id AND U.group_id = V.parent_group_id
WHERE V.id = xxx AND V.group_id = xxx
```

To make the join run efficiently, the following fields MUST be defined as Indices for those tables:

- `V.group_id`
- `V.user_id`
- `V.parent_group_id`
- `U.group_id`

To make the query run efficiently, it should not use `SELECT *` (specify ***only*** the columns you need), and the query should be optimized

## We can't help if we can't see your data and code.

Ultimately, you're asking a community to help you solve a MySQL performance issue on a large data-set, but are unwilling or unable to show us any of the table-structure, the full-query, or sample source-data and desired output.

As long we we're flying blind, there's nothing we can do to help.